# Positioning li.active to the center of it's parent element, and shifting the remaining items around it

Tags: css, calc

I have a horizontal list that I'm trying to position so that the `li.active` is the centre of parent element.

```css
div {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;

}
ul {
  transform: translateX( calc(50% - (150px / 2) - (150px * 6)) );
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  direction:rtl;
}
li {
  display:inline-block;
  background:blue;
  height:300px;
  width:150px;

}
li.active {
  background:white;
  background:green;
}

span {
  display:block;
  width:150px;
  background: purple;
  height:150px;

  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left: calc(50% - 75px);
}
* {
  font-size:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<span></span>
```

Do note, I'll be adding items dynamically, so I've set the `ul` with `direction:rtl;`, so when a new item is added it will not affect the `transform: translateX` positioning.

In this example: http://jsbin.com/fafedowaza/edit?html,css,output - I'm to center the green block, so that it'll underlap the purple block.

How may I achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking for a transition mostly, or centering the active one?  I'd say you could re-order the list items with the active one in the center and then repaint the dom, everytime the active one changes.

Comment: Wanting to transition

Comment: Off the top of my head I'm thinking you could get the offset-x of each element from the parent and move them left or right depending on their relative distance from center - left / right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Transform: translateX

I changed `display` property for `ul` to `inline-block` so it can rely on it's content width instead of parent's. Also I noticed you count the green block twice when you wrote the `calc` statement, change (150px * 6) to (150px * 5).
This solution works only when the window (or parent) is at least 900px width (6*150px).

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  transform: translateX( calc(50% - (150px / 2) - (150px * 5)));
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: rtl;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  height: 300px;
  width: 150px;
}
li.active {
  background: green;
}
span {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  background: purple;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 75px);
}
* {
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<span></span>
```

### 2. Position: absolute

This one will work regardless of parent's width. I'm not sure why `transform: translateX` behave itself this way, haven't use it much, but looks like `position: absolute` did the trick.

```css
div {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - (150px / 2) - (150px * 5));
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: rtl;
  display: inline-block;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  height: 300px;
  width: 150px;
}
li.active {
  background: green;
}
span {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  background: purple;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 75px);
}
* {
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<span></span>
```

### 3. Adding items dynamically

I'm not sure what you meant when you said that you can add items dynamically and it won't affect the positioning, because you set `calc` statement based on quantity of `li` elements. This way, when you add a `li` you should change the `calc` statement or at least add another css class to `ul` which will override the old rule. If you're planning to add/remove `li` elements via JavaScript you will probably use it for fixing the positioning too. If your list of items is going to be dynamic on the server side, you can set a css class to your `ul` accordingly to the quantity of it's `li` elements.

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard way to center elements, that consist of setting the left property to 50%, and then translate it again 50%.

In your case, a variation  of this technique is useful, but since you are using rtl direction, it mut be changed to use  the right property:

Added

```
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translateX(75px);
```

to the ul

```css
div {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;

}
ul {
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  direction:rtl;
  /* new style */
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translateX(75px);
}
li {
  display:inline-block;
  background:blue;
  height:300px;
  width:150px;

}
li.active {
  background:white;
  background:green;
}

span {
  display:block;
  width:150px;
  background: purple;
  height:150px;

  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left: calc(50% - 75px);
}
* {
  font-size:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<span></span>
```